# R Markdown - adding an automatic macro to an MS-word document

Tags: r, vba, ms-word, r-markdown

I am currently generating word documents with Rmarkdown. But the formating is a bit difficult compared to an HTML output. One of the technical solution I could use would be to add a macro on my word file and make it execute automaticaly on opening.

The following macro should do the trick for automatic execution :

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Msgbox "Hello World!"

End Sub
```

How would one adds this macro to the doc knitted with Rmarkdown ? How do one make sure it executes correctly on opening ?

Comment: I think you'll need to put the vba macro in the rmarkdown docx template (look up the `reference_docx` parameter) before rendering your document (meaning it isn't R code putting the VBA in there). As to making sure it executes ... that's completely in the hands of Microsoft, Word, and the security settings of the person opening the document. (And I think you'll want the [`Document_Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.open) function.)

Comment: Why do you need it to automatically execute when it opens? And why dont you just add it manually to your Word document?

Comment: @braX : Because the end goal is to produce multiple reports on a frequent basis...

Comment: Ah ok - well, you dont need to put macros into a bunch of files to do that... you can easily write a program that will open a normal DOCX file and process its contents and save it... or do whatever you want with it... the security limitation here shouldnt prevent that

Comment: Without understanding what formatting issues you are having.  I suggest reading these two references: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html, https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html

Comment: Note that the macro name is incorrect for automatic execution when a document opens. In Word it must be: `AutoOpen`